# Unable to debug ASP .NET 1.0 Application

Tags: asp.net, registry, .net-1.0

When I try to debug a web site in .NET 1.0, I get the following error
"Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging on the web server. Could not read key from registry"

I was not able to find any documentation on this particular error for not not being able to read the key from registry.

I did look at [Microsoft KB For This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306172), but, it does not have anything for the registry read error.

EDIT: I found a work around for this. Add the username that aspnet_wp.exe is running under to the Administartors group on your PC. This is a very bad thing because it exposes a security hole on your machine.
But, it is still not clear what "other" rights does this account need in order to "read key from registry."

Comment: Does it say what registry key it is trying to read?  If the registry key is trying to be read by your code, you have to make sure you are requesting read-only access to the key.  With a default IIS setup your app runs with credentials that probably don't have write access to most reg keys, esp. HKLM

Comment: No! It does not say which key it is trying to read. 
When I start the project without debugging (Ctrl + F5), it runs fine.
This is in VS 2002 by the way.

Comment: Look in the security event log for any failure audit entires when you run the app in debug mode.

Comment: I looked in there as you suggested. There are no failure entries in it. This is really wierd!

Answer (score 0):

Consider running the [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) from SysInternals. It should show your which registry keys get denied.